# How to buld a temp buffer with clickable text like `occur`?

Tags: buffers, occur

I have this LaTeX code:

```
\macroFoo}
...
...
\macroBar}
...
...
\macro{Baz}
...
...
```

I want to build a temp buffer that shows all the `\macro{<arg>}` together with a progressive number, i.e.

```
1 \macro{Foo}
2 \macro{Bar}
3 \macro{Baz}
```

but with all the macros clickable like it happens using `M-x occur RET \\macro{ RET`.

I'm able to write a function that does what I want except for the `occur` style part.

```
(defun mikey ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((revert-without-query '(".*"))
           (main-buffer (buffer-name))
           (tmpfile (concat (make-temp-name "tmp")
                            ".tex"))
           (count 0))

      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\\\<macro\\>" nil t)
        (save-excursion
          (let* ((pos1 (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
                 (pos2 (copy-marker (progn
                                      (forward-sexp)
                                      (point)))))

            (write-region pos1 pos2 tmpfile t)
            (write-region "\n" nil tmpfile 'append))))

      (with-current-buffer
          (let ((enable-local-variables ()))
            (find-file-noselect tmpfile))

        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\\\macro\\)" nil t)
          (setq count (+ count 1))
          (replace-match (concat (number-to-string count)
                                 ": \\1")
                         t))
        (save-buffer))

      ;; open tmpfile in a new window
      (find-file-other-window tmpfile)

      ;; delete tmpfile physically
      (delete-file tmpfile)

      ;; move cursor to main buffer
      (find-file-other-window main-buffer)

      )))
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: IIUC, see [Defining clickable text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

Comment: I've already consulted the "GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual", but there are no examples for doing what I'm interested in, so I don't know where to start. I've also tried several times to look at the definition of `occur-1` in `replace.el`, but it's too difficult for my current knowledge.

Comment: Maybe using the higher-level Widgets library might be easier. There is a complete example of a Customize-type user interface (which is exactly why the library exists). See [User Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html#User-Interface) and the [code for it](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html#Programming-Example) - in particular, look at the implementation of  the `other work` embedded button.